# GetService with IOptionsMonitor<Settings> returns null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have the following on an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<Settings>(new Settings { DefaultPageSize = 40 });

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var result = provider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<Settings>>();
```

On the last line `result` is `null` ... Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
services.AddSingleton<Settings>(...
```

Does not automatically associate `Settings` with the `IOptionsMonitor` feature.

Need to configure that `Settings` class as an option with the service collection using one of the Options pattern extensions

For example

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

// Options bound and configured by a delegate
services.Configure<Settings>(option => {
    option.DefaultPageSize = 40;
});

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var result = provider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<Settings>>();
```

#### Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core: Configure simple options with a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-simple-options-with-a-delegate-1)